# iOS 8 Push Notification Action not working in background activation mode

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios8

I am experiencing a problem with the following lines of code :

```
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *cancelAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    cancelAction.identifier = kCancelIdentifier;
    cancelAction.title = @"Cancel";
    cancelAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    cancelAction.destructive = YES;
    cancelAction.authenticationRequired = YES;
```

When responding to this action of the push notification, it will always open up the application rather than performing task in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `activationMode` for `acceptAction` not `cancelAction`.